# Is there a way to automatically bring up a plot in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, spice

Other spice sims have graphical elements or instructions to bring up graphs when you run a simulation.

I know you can click on various points in LT spice an bring up plots, is there a way to include graphical elements or add an instruction to bring up a graph when you run the simulation?

Comment: does LTspice have any scripting capability?

Comment: Yeah. There's a plot file that, if it has the same name as the .asc, will drive the plot choices. I don't do this. But if you look in the educational subdirs, I think you will find an example or two. Look there. I know this because when I grab and run some of them, they automatically plot the right things for me.

Comment: @jsotola It has scripting capability in the fact that you can drop text into it and it ends up in the spice scripting.

Comment: found this ... it might lead to a solution... https://acidbourbon.wordpress.com/2019/11/26/seamless-integration-of-ltspice-in-python-numpy-signal-processing/

Answer (score 1):

You can save plots and then load them.

When you select the plot pane the **File** menu will change, there will be items for **Save Plot Settings** and **Save Plot Setting As**.  You will also get another top level menu **Plot Settings** with some other plot related options. Setup the plot the way you want, add the traces, adjust the axes, add annotations, whatever. Then do **Save Plot Settings** and it will save a .plt file with the same base name as your .asc file. Now if you change a resistor value or something and then run the simulation again the plot pane will come up the way it usually does, select the plot pane and press your space bar, it will load the saved plot settings, but the traces will reflect the changes to the schematic. You have to be careful of node name changes though, if your saved plot has something like V(n004) and you change the schematic enough that n004 is a different point in the circuit it won't work right. Try to use named nodes for your plots.

The **Save Plot Settings** As lets you pick a file name so you can save multiple plots for the same schematic and load the one you want, but it won't load with the space bar, you have to do it manually from the **Plot Settings** menu.

You can annotate your plots with text and drawing elements as shown [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-annotating-schematic-waveform-plots.html). You can also put a cursor on a trace (click the trace name at the top of the plot pane) and move it to a point on the trace, then click F4 (or use the menu item under **Plot Settings / Notes & Annotations**) to label the cursor position with the values at that point.

Comment: I'm asking more about if you can include a .op line and have a plot pop up

Comment: @VoltageSpike Ah... not that I know of. I kind of remember looking into that a while back and getting nowhere with it. I'm interested if anyone else comes up with something.